# Creating a Trigger which execute on particular days of week (Quartz Scheduler API)

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to build a Trigger in Quartz Scheduler API which should get executed with following criteria.

1. Start on particular date (Jan 25, 2012)
2. Start at predefined time (08.00.00 AM)
3. Every Week.
4. Can be scheduled for alternate week or every 3 week (if not every week)
5. On these particular days of week (Monday,Tuesday,Friday etc)

I have created the following expression

```
newTrigger().withIdentity(cronTriggerDTO.getTiggerId(), "simpleGroup")
        .startAt(getTriggerExecutionDate(cronTriggerDTO))
        .withSchedule(calendarIntervalSchedule().withIntervalInWeeks 
                  (cronTriggerDTO.getWeeklyInterval())).build();
```

but I am confused how I should add the condition to execute this trigger on particular days of week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder

```
Set daysOfWeek = new HashSet();
daysOfWeek.add(1);
daysOfWeek.add(2);
daysOfWeek.add(5);

newTrigger().withIdentity(cronTriggerDTO.getTiggerId(), "simpleGroup")
    .startAt(getTriggerExecutionDate(cronTriggerDTO))
    .withSchedule(dailyTimeIntervalSchedule()
       .onDaysOfTheWeek(daysOfWeek)
          .startingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(8,0)))
    .build();
```

Comment: it looks good but i also have to set weekfrequency might be some user want to set trigger with everythig same but executing every alternate week like `calendarIntervalSchedule().withIntervalInWeeks(2)`

Comment: i have already pointed out that in my post with conditions 3.added up more details :)

Comment: This makes your requirements too complex to use a builder for the scheduler. Use a cron expression as suggested :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(String cronExpression)`, like this:

```
newTrigger().withIdentity(cronTriggerDTO.getTiggerId(), "simpleGroup")
    .startAt(getTriggerExecutionDate(cronTriggerDTO))
    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 * * 1,2,5"))
    .build();
```

Comment: my values are coming from UI and i am building this based on those values.for weekdays user will click on the checkboxes for weekdays, else i will surely go for cron-expression

Comment: Why not create an expression based on the values from the UI?

Comment: @user702325 What does `cronTriggerDTO.getWeeklyInterval()` return? Maybe you can adapt it to the cron values.

Comment: @Nacho `getWeeklyInterval()` just return int value indicating if it needs to get triggered every week or alternate etc

Comment: @his: i am agree about expression value but i am looking in to some build in mechanism to handle this

Answer (score 0):

Use cron trigger and below is the simple way to prepare cron expression

```
  int second = 53;//prepare from the time selected from UI(fire time)
  int minute=0;
  int hour=8;
  String dayOfWeek="1,3";//prepare it from the days you get from UI(give check box values as 1 for SUN,....)

  String cronExpression = String.format("%d %d %d ? * %s",second,minute , hour, dayOfWeek);

         newTrigger()
    .withIdentity(cronTriggerDTO.getTiggerId(), "simpleGroup")//
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule(cronExpression)//
    .startAt(getTriggerExecutionDate(cronTriggerDTO))
    .build();
```

Then schedule the job..,hope this helps you.

Comment: i know about the cron expression and if there are no other way will go for that,all currently i am looking is to use some build in mechanisn on quartz if its there