# Cron Expression : Run on specific time (1:30 pm , 15:24 pm) on MON and WED only

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I was just checked on http://www.cronmaker.com/  and try to create cron expression for following scenario.
  Run the job on two specific times at 1:24, and 3:34 on monday and tuesday.

I was generated following expression for that.

```
     0 24,34 12,13 ? * MON,WED *

    1.  Monday, May 1, 2017 12:24 PM
    2.  Monday, May 1, 2017 12:34 PM
    3.  Monday, May 1, 2017 1:24 PM
    4.  Monday, May 1, 2017 1:34 PM
```

But got the following result.The problem is that it run 4 times in a day but want to run only two time. Is Possible ? to make cron expression for the scenario.

Comment: I'm tempted to flag this as duplicate. A simple [question search for "quartz days of week"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=quartz+days+of+week) returns plenty of examples on how you could do that. Please have a look at the good answers in there.

Comment: @walen actually I want to run in one expression , not in two expression.I konw about how to run in two expression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Trigger which execute on particular days of week (Quartz Scheduler API)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000054/creating-a-trigger-which-execute-on-particular-days-of-week-quartz-scheduler-ap)

Answer (score 2):

A Cron expression will perform all combinations, so you'll need to define two separate expressions.

```
0 24 13 ? * MON,WED *

1.  Monday, May 1, 2017 1:24 PM
2.  Wednesday, May 3, 2017 1:24 PM

0 34 15 ? * MON,WED *

1.  Monday, May 1, 2017 3:34 PM
2.  Wednesday, May 3, 2017 3:34 PM
```

In [this blogpost](http://techniqpatch.blogspot.be/2013/08/how-to-add-multiple-triggers-for-job-in.html) you can find an example of how to add multiple triggers with [quartz-scheduler](/questions/tagged/quartz-scheduler).

Comment: actually I want to run in one expression , not in two expression.I konw about how to run in two expression